# How to test multiple roles of a WebApps concurrently using browsers

Tags: testing, web-applications, browser, session-cookies

I'm in search of a method to test multiple roles of an application with a browser. For this question, I need solutions for interactive operation, **user assumed to being signed-in**.

Target OS would be **primarily OS X**, but please provide **Windows solutions too**.

All browsers I'm aware of, **store cookies centralized in a browser**. If I'm signed-in to a web-app with say role A and then sign-in as role B, role A gets hidden - because most **web-apps share a single session token**, which identifies user's role.

Do solutions exist, to test **two roles in parallel in a browser**? A browser, which has different *separated identities*?

Due to certain reasons, opening two different browsers wouldn't be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this:

Firefox has a feature named [Profiles](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments). Using [Firefox' command line arguments](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments), one can create multiple separated profiles:

[image: Firefox's profile manager]

E.g. on OS X, the Firefox' Profile Manager opens using this command:

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -ProfileManager
```

To have two different Firefox instances run with different profiles on OS X, one needs to create a copy of the Firefox application.

Still, I'd be happy to learn of **solutions for other browsers**. Or integrated solution, which **doesn't force me to copy the browser app**.

Comment: In Chrome, you can open an incognito window:
http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95464
Though beware, each incognito window will share the same session information (separate from the non-incognito windows).

Comment: @Noyo Thx! But incognito/private browsing isn't a solution here.

Comment: @Noyo Regarding this question: Manual testing. Just refined my question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on a Mac, you can use `open -n /Applications/BrowserName.app` for whichever browser you want (though newer versions of Firefox apparently require slightly more work: https://superuser.com/questions/396434/how-to-open-a-new-firefox-window-with-terminal). This command will open an entirely new instance of the browser each time you run it.

Depending on how you're testing, you may want to clear cookies on browser close, though cookies shouldn't interfere while the browsers are running. (Not tested.)

Comment: Great! Does this establish a separated sandbox with own preferences and such?

Comment: This should be the case, though I haven't tested. I assume, though, that the preferences of any new browser instance will be identical to those of the most recently closed instance. (Last time I checked, most or all major browsers write update their preference files on browser exit.)

Comment: Time for someone to write an app, which starts an app with a new fresh sandbox, separate preferences and such. Obviously, this app wouldn't pass AppStore guidelines ;-)